# Preserve Special Charcters While Migrating Data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, clob

I am using the below code to extract data from source legacy database and putting into a CLOB column in target 11g database

```
RTRIM (  
            XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (  
                       e,  
                       REPLACE (  
                          REGEXP_REPLACE (  
                             REPLACE (prod_desc, CHR (10), '~~~'),  
                             '[[:cntrl:]]'),  
                          '~~~',  
                          CHR (10)),  
                       CHR (10)) ORDER BY prod_date DESC).EXTRACT ('//text()').getclobval (),  
            CHR (10))
```

prod_desc column has '<' , '>' '&' and other special characters, these are getting replaced with `&lt;` `&gt;` , `&amp;`  respectively.

How can I preserve the above values even I migrate the data from source to target?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? `'<' , '>', '&'` are replaced by `'<' , '>', '&'`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sorry, there was a formatting issue, corrected my question.

Comment: Just use `datapump` over database link

Comment: @klashxx DBA has provided with a table with the data, do not have access to the legacy neither do have the the option of datapump. Thanks

Comment: @klashxx Moreover I have observed that the source data which I have is having the original format. When I use my code which is posted in the question is converting the characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a side effect of Oracle `XML` tools.

You can reverse it with:

```
SQL> SELECT UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,'>')))) AS XML FROM dual;
XML
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<E>></E>
```

**vs**

```
SQL> SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,'>'))) AS XML FROM dual;
XML
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<E>&gt;</E>
```

Comment: Not sure how to use this with the my SQL statement though.